# Strange behavior of Java code with static attribute

Tags: java, static

I do not have much to ask really. Heck I don't even know what the question should say. Basically, this Java code works fine without any compilation errors.

```
public class Application {
    static String[][] tiles;

    public Application() {
        tiles = new String[9][9];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Application app = new Application();
        Grid mines = new Grid();
        mines.fillTiles(tiles, 9, 9, 10);
    }
}

class Grid {
    Random rand;

    public void fillTiles(String[][] tiles, int rowSize, int colSize,
            int numMines) {
        rand = new Random();
        int rowIndex;
        int columnIndex;
        while (numMines > 0) {
            rowIndex = rand.nextInt(rowSize);
            columnIndex = rand.nextInt(colSize);
            tiles[rowIndex][columnIndex] = "M";
            numMines--;
        }
    }
}
```

But, when I remove the line

```
Application app = new Application();
```

from the main method in the first class, it is throwing a NullPointerException at

```
tiles[rowIndex][columnIndex] = new String("M");
```

Any reason why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You notice that you have instantiated your array in your constructor?

```
static String[][] tiles;

public Application() {
    tiles = new String[9][9];  <--- Here
}
```

So, if you don't instantiate your `Application` using `new Application()`, your array would not be initialized, and your reference will be pointing to null.

Also, it is not a good idea to initialize your static variables in constructor. Ideally, you should initialize your static array in a `static initializer block` or at the place of declaration itself: -

```
static {
    tiles = new String[9][9];
}
```

or

```
static String[][] tiles = new String[9][9];
```

If you initialize your array in your constructor, it will be re-initialized for every instance, every time you create one. As `static` variables are common to all the instances. So, the change you make to your `static` variable, will be reflected in all your instances.

Answer (score 10):

```
Application app = new Application();
```

If you don't instantiate `Application`, `tiles` will be pointing to `null`. Operation on null reference results in `NullPointerException`.

Your Array initialization logic is in constructor.

```
public Application() {
        tiles = new String[9][9];
    }
```

Constructor will be executed only on Object creation (`new Application()`)

If you don't want to do `Application app = new Application();`

Just change  `static String[][] tiles=new String[9][9];`

Defining `static` array variable doesn't mean that instantiation will happen on load. It just means that that variable is class variable.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are initializing `tiles = new String[9][9];` in your constructor. You constructor is only called when you use `new` to create the object instance as `new Application()`.

If you don't want to use the constructor, declare your static variable with initialization as:

```
    static String[][] tiles = new String[9][9];
```

That should work fine without constructor call.

Answer (score 2):

I think I might know the reason why:

```
public class Application {
    static String[][] tiles;

    public Application() {
        tiles = new String[9][9];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Application app = new Application();
        Grid mines = new Grid();
        mines.fillTiles(tiles, 9, 9, 10);
    }
}
```

In this you have a static 2d array that holds strings called tiles. However, you only initialize it in the constructor of Application. Thus when calling "mines.fillTiles(tiles", tiles is still null and

```
tiles[rowIndex][columnIndex] = new String("M");
```

will throw a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing the array in the constructor of an instance.  If you create another instance after the first, it will re-initialize the static member.

Comment: No, he's *initializing* the array in the constructor. It's *declared* in the class scope (as it would have to be, given that it's a static variable).